# How to get first two element with a condition from a multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Is there anyways to get first two element of each profile_id using php

```
array(
    array(['type'] => album,['profile_id'] => 1),
    array(['type'] => video,['profile_id'] => 1),
    array(['type'] => image,['profile_id'] => 1),

    array(['type'] => album,['profile_id'] => 2),
    array(['type'] => video,['profile_id'] => 2),
    array(['type'] => scenes,['profile_id'] => 2),
    array(['type'] => image,['profile_id'] => 2),

    array(['type'] => album,['profile_id'] => 3),
    array(['type'] => video,['profile_id'] => 3),
    array(['type'] => album,['profile_id'] => 3),
)
```

Expected Result

```
array(
    array(['type'] => album,['profile_id'] => 1),
    array(['type'] => video,['profile_id'] => 1),

    array(['type'] => album,['profile_id'] => 2),
    array(['type'] => video,['profile_id'] => 2),

    array(['type'] => album,['profile_id'] => 3),
    array(['type'] => video,['profile_id'] => 3),
)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Loop the array
- put into new array upto count 2 if profile_id == next profile_id
- if profile_id != next profile_id reset count and repeat step 2.

It's better not to post the exact code. :D

Comment: thanks for your response. i missed step 3 and now its working :)